# How to determine if an update was successful

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateOwnerSelectedSkinId]
        (
            @emailAddress VARCHAR(100),
            @skinId int,
            @ownerSkinGroup VARCHAR(100)
        )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        Update dbo.Owner
         SET  
         SkinId = @skinId, OwnerSkinGroup = @ownerSkinGroup
        WHERE
            EmailAddress = @emailAddress
    END
```

At the moment if I call this with a valid or invalid email, the value returned by the SP is always 0. How can I determine if the update worked or not.

Comment: If you are calling SQL Server from something like Java or C# the driver should return the number of records updated.

Comment: Have you checked **[`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**? Or even you may think of `BEGIN TRY ... END TRY BEGIN CATCH ... END CATCH` for success or failure.

Comment: It's being called from command object in C# using ExecuteReader

Comment: The return value of an SP means if the SP was successful, `0` for yes, anything else for no. Not updating any rows doesn't mean a statement was not successful; just like if a `SELECT` statement returns no rows doesn't mean that the statement errored. It simply means that there were no eligible rows. If you want to "return" a scalar value from an SP, you should be looking at `OUTPUT` parameters.

Comment: You are using ExecuteReader, use ExecuteNonQuery instead, it will return the number of rows affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  "successful" means that any record/s updated, you can set `SET NOCOUNT OFF` and the number of rows affected will be returned to the client.

In you comments you say you use `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`, but your SP does not return any result-set. You should instead use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2) which will return the number of rows affected.